# Cómo puedo comparar si la imagen tiene el mismo nombre?

Tags: php, poo

Como lo indico en el título, busco validar si la imagen tiene el mismo nombre.

Quiero comparar si el usuario selecciona la misma imagen, mandar un alert de error, el alert si tengo idea como hacerlo, pero la comparacion no se si debe crear otro if anidado para poderlo realizar.

Este es mi código

```php
if($_POST['funcion']=='cambiar_avatar'){
    $id = $_POST['id_logo_prod'];
    if(($_FILES['photo']['type']=='image/jpeg')||($_FILES['photo']['type']=='image/png')||($_FILES['photo']['type']=='image/gif')){
        $nombre=uniqid().'-'.$_FILES['photo']['name'];                 /* uniqid comando para no guardar una imagen con el mismo nombre concatenando el $_FILES */
        //echo $nombre;                                                /* comprobar que envia por medio de consola de chrome */
        $ruta='../img/prod/'.$nombre;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$ruta);        /* comando para guardar imagenes en la ruta */
        $producto->cambiar_logo($id,$nombre);
        foreach($producto->objetos as $objeto){
            if($objeto->avatar!='prod_default.png'){
                unlink('../img/prod'.$objeto->avatar);           /*borra una imagen si le damos la url, borrando el antiguo avatar*/
            }                                    
        }
        $json=array();
        $json[]=array(
            'ruta'=>$ruta,
            'alert'=>'edit'
        );
        $jsonstring = json_encode($json[0]);
        echo $jsonstring;
    }
    if($objeto->avatar=='avatar'){

    }
    else{
        $json=array();
        $json[]=array(
            'alert'=>'noedit'
        );
        $jsonstring = json_encode($json[0]);
        echo $jsonstring;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema???

Comment: Puedes ponerla como texto. Nadie va a replicar tu código desde una imagen. Voy a reversar la edición, vale? Edita tu pregunta nuevamente y explícanos mejor cuál es el problema con tu código.

Comment: Hola Sergio. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona exactamente (indícalo en el código)? ¿Qué obtienes?  ¿Qué esperas obtener? ¿Qué pruebas has hecho? ¿Con qué resultados?

Comment: hola @Alfabravo ahi ya se ve el codigo? a mi me aparece el codigo

Comment: @A.Cedano hola lo que quiero hacer es que valide si una imagen es igual me mande un alert de error, tengo idea de como hacer el alert, pero la comparacion no!

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que puedes recuperar el nombre actual de la imagen del producto, y que algun uniqid() esta en la imagen anterior:

```
$rutaActual = '../img/prod/'.$producto->logo; // UNIQUEID-nombre.png
$nombreActual = explode("-",$rutaActual,2)[1]; //nombre despues del uniqid()
if ($nombreActual==$_FILES['photo']['name']){
   // mismo nombre
}
```

Creo que la idea mas importante seria verificar si el archivo subido es el mismo (igual contenido) mas que el nombre (puede ser otra imagen con el mismo nombre). Por lo que puedes comparar que el contenido binario sea el mismo que la imagen original usando `md5`:

```
$rutaActual = '../img/prod/'.$producto->logo; // UNIQUEID-nombre.png
$md5Actual = md5_file($producto->logo); 
$md5Nuevo = md5_file($_FILES['photo']['tmpname']);
if ($md5Actual == $md5Nuevo){
   // mismo archivo en contenido
}
```